# Error fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin angular

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, types, fullcalendar

I have this error:

```
Error: Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin.
```

When I added resourceTimeGridPlugin to plugins.

My code:

```
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import { FullCalendarComponent } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import resourceTimeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include the Calendar Core object in your component:

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
```

In your constructor you have to add this:

```
 constructor() { 
    const name = Calendar.name; 
 }
```

Full example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  calendarOptions = {
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
  };

 constructor() { 
    const name = Calendar.name;
  }
}
```

This forces loading/initializing of the core component and the VDom reference before the plugin needs it.

Comment: That will work for now, but as the code is modified over time, if `Calendar` becomes unused, TypeScript will elide the import and it will fail again. To avoid that possibility, be explicit as there is a syntax for this. `import '@fullcalendar/core';`. This means import this module for its side effects.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to solve this in my project.

in my module import in this order and register my plugins.

```
import { FullCalendarModule } from "@fullcalendar/angular";
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import momentPlugin from '@fullcalendar/moment';
import rrulePlugin from '@fullcalendar/rrule';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';

FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([
  dayGridPlugin,
  interactionPlugin,
  listPlugin,
  momentPlugin,
  rrulePlugin,
  timeGridPlugin
]);
```

in the component I use this inside my constructor just before I prepare my calendarOptions

`forwardRef(() =>Calendar);`